# Terminal Behavior 1235w

Tags: login, root

I have downloaded latest version of Ubuntu 16.04 and am unable to initialize root login administrative access permissions inside of Terminal ?

Comment: You don't log in as root directly, that account is disabled by default. Instead, you use `sudo` to run single commands with elevated privileges ("as root") using your own account's password.

Answer (score 0):

The command that will give you a root console to work in is

```
 sudo -i
```

The best way to use "root" is by using

```
sudo
```

before you enter a command. For example

```
sudo apt update
```

This will initiate the command with elevated priveledges.

You CAN enable the root account, if that is what you mean, however I would advise against it as it has its security risks.

To do this you must first set a password for root.

```
~$ sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

then unlock it

```
~$ sudo passwd -u root
passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

To lock the root account again

```
~$ sudo passwd -l root
passwd: password expiry information changed.
```